# How can I create a custom form settings to my custom field formatter?

Tags: entities, 8

I need to add form settings to my custom display format, can you provide me with an example?

To be clear I just want to add some fields to the format settings form.

[image: format settings form]

Comment: What settings are you talking about? Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: thanks for answer, I already added a image to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you need to figure out how something works, look at examples that already do what you want. In your case, that's the [ImageFormatter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21image%21src%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldFormatter%21ImageFormatter.php/class/ImageFormatter/8) plugin.

Specifically, you are looking for the methods `defaultSettings()`, `settingsForm()` and `settingsSummary()`. Implement them, define the form for you settings, specificy default settings and for improved user experience, implement the summary method to give users a short summary of the current settings.

That's all, in viewElements(); you can then access your settings with getSetting().

Comment: Thanks!!! its work! before your answer I was checking that, but I was having doubt.